# Linking Jquery, CSS and JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I got a jQuery code (logformquery.js) and CSS code (mystyles.css) for a jsp page. I saved CSS file in a folder "css". And wrote "" in jsp file, in the  tag. But I don't know how to link the jQuery code with my jsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below, assuming the css Folder is the same directory as the jsp file.

CSS

`<link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

JS

`<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/logformquery.js.js"></script>`

The javascript, assuming that it is in a JS Folder

Comment: Thank You BlackPearl. It was useful.